# How can I create a discrete cosine spectrum analyzer for a computer network using LabWindows CVI?

Tags: cvi, labwindows

Can someone help me with a project in NI Lab Windows CVI?The project has the following specifications->Project theme: Discrete cosine spectrum analyzer;Application: computer network;User interface: single panel;Input: client aquires signal, send;Processing: server receive, discrete cosine transform;Output: log scale frequency display, generate;
I don't really know how to work in NI Lab Windows CVI, and I would like to ask for your help.